# NSOrderedSame что делает?

Tags: objective-c

Я не понимаю что делает строчка `[nextCard.name caseInsensitiveCompare:theName] == **NSOrderedSame**` из метода экземпляра.

Чему должна равняться `nextCard.name caseInsensitiveCompare:theName`?

Буду благодарен за разжевывание механики этого куска.

Сам метод:

```
-(AddressCard *) lookup: (NSString *) theName {
for (AddressCard *nextCard in book) {
    if ([nextCard.name caseInsensitiveCompare:theName] == NSOrderedSame)
       return nextCard;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот метод проверяется строки на равенства, при этом не обращая внимания на то, написаны слова с заглавными буквами или нет. Например, `@"One more THING"` и `@"one more thing"` будут одинаковыми строками. Этот метод не просто возвращает значение YES или NO, а что именно он возвращает уже можете сами посмотреть. Конкретно ваш метод что делает, пробегаясь по массиву элементов сравнивает поле name с входящим параметром функции, и если они совпадают, то возвращает этот объект, если нет, то просто возвращает `nil`. Вот только одно не понятно, где объявлен массив book.

Comment: Илья, спасибо за ответ! Массив book объявлен раньше и с ним всё хорошо :) Но, я не совсем правильно выразил свой вопрос. В цикле for последовательно сравниваются элементы массива с  переменной theName в [nextCard.name caseInsensitiveCompare:theName], а вот дальше мне не понятно, знак равенства и "NSOrderedSame" чему должно соответствовать? Для чего мы пишем "== NSOrderedSame"?

Comment: @Dubplate это и есть как раз такие сравнение возвращаемого значения функции с nsorderedsame, знак двойного равенства это сравнение. Вы сильно плаваете в основных понятиях, посмотрите книгу сила objective-c или другие книги по основам objective-c.

Comment: согласен, читаю сейчас книгу Objective-C Стивена Кочана, этот пример оттуда.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Может немного коряво, объясню для таких же как я новичков.  "NSOrderedSame" словосочетание которое говорит о том, что два объекта равны. Т.е. метод caseInsensitiveCompare  возвращает "NSOrderedSame" если nextCard.name и "theName" совпадут, при этом выполняется равенство "== NSOrderedSame)" и конструкция if выполняется.

Comment: @Dubplate да все верно) двигайтесь в том же направлении))